# Jest mocking with Next useRouter

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks, jestjs, enzyme

this is the file I'm testing -

```
import React from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import Item from '../Item';
import { getBaseURL } from '../../utils/url';
import { usePath } from '../../hooks/usePath';
import ITEMS from '../../constants/items';
import styles from './itemlist.module.scss';

const ItemList = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const path = usePath();
  const queryIndex = router?.asPath?.lastIndexOf('?') || -1;
  const query = queryIndex !== -1 ? router.asPath.slice(queryIndex) : '';

  return (
    <div className={styles.itemWrapper}>
      <h2 className={styles.title}>Popular Items</h2>
      <div className={styles.itemList}>
        {ITEMS.map(({ name, url }) => (
          <Item
            key={name}
            name={name}
            url={`${getBaseURL()}${url}${query}`}
            active={path === url}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ItemList;
```

This is what I have so far in my test file -

```
/* eslint-disable camelcase */
/* eslint-env jest */
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import ItemList from '.';
import usePath from '../../hooks/usePath';

jest.mock('../../hooks/usePath');
jest.mock('next/router');
jest.mock('../../utils/url');
jest.mock('../../constants/items');

describe('ItemList Component', () => {
  it('should mount without an error', () => {
    const shallowRender = shallow(<ItemList />);
    expect(shallowRender.exists()).toBe(true);
  });

  it('should form the page url links including any existing query string', () => {
    const shallowRender = shallow(<ItemList />);
    expect(
      shallowRender
        .find('Item')
        .at(0)
        .prop('url')
    ).toEqual('// Not sure how to test this');
  });

  // it('should make the current url active', () => {
  // });
});
```

What I would like to test is if it forms/passes in the correct url to the Item component and whether it makes the Item component active if the path matches the url.

I'm not sure how best to mock this? I have started to write the test for the first scenario but I think that usePath and useRouter need to be mocked someway.

This is the usePath file -

```
const getPath = router =>
  router.pathname.includes('[item]')
    ? router.pathname.replace('[item]', router.query.item)
    : router.pathname;

export const usePath = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  return getPath(router);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One choise is to mock ITEMS and useRouter hook so you check if your component render correctly:

```
it('should form the page url links including any existing query string', () => {
    const name = 'Name';
    const url = 'Url';
    ITEMS = [{ name, url }];
    const shallowRender = shallow(<ItemList />);
    const renderItem = shallowRender.find('Item').at(0);
    expect(renderItem.prop('url')).toEqual(url);
    expect(renderItem.prop('name')).toEqual(name);
  });
```

For the active test you have to mock usePath:

```
jest.mock('../../hooks/usePath', () => ({
  usePath: jest.fn(),
}));
```

so you can try to do this:

```
it('should make the current url active', () => {
    const name = 'Name';
    const url = 'Url';
    ITEMS = [{ name, url }];
    usePath.mockImplementation(() => url);
    const shallowRender = shallow(<ItemList />);
    const renderItem = shallowRender.find('Item').at(0);
    expect(renderItem.prop('active')).toEqual(true);
  });
```

for not active test:

```
it('should make other url not active', () => {
    const name = 'Name';
    const url = 'Url';
    ITEMS = [{ name, url }];
    usePath.mockImplementation(() => 'otherUrl');
    const shallowRender = shallow(<ItemList />);
    const renderItem = shallowRender.find('Item').at(0);
    expect(renderItem.prop('active')).toEqual(false);
  });
```

In the same time you could mock useRoute as you need. For example:

```
jest.mock('next/router');
```

and in the test you can mock as the follow:

```
useRouter.mockImplementation(()=>({pathname:'', ......}))
```